# Play Framework begginner. Trying to implement model

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am learning Play framework and I solve some practice problems. I want to compile the code but I have a error and I can not figure out what the error is.

I expect an output like this:
[image: output]

HomeController.java

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {

public Result index() {
    int level = 1;

    Item item = new Item();
    item.User = "user1";
    item.timestamp = LocalTime.now();
    item.message = "the first message testing";

    Item item2 = new Item();
    item2.User = "user2";
    item2.timestamp = LocalTime.now();
    item2.message = "the second message testing";


    java.util.List<String> list= {item, item2};
    return ok(index.render("it works!", level, asScalaBuffer(list)));
}
}
```

index.scala.html

```
@(message: String)(level:Int, list:Seq[Item])

@main("Welcome to Play") {
<h1>@message</h1>

@listContainer{
<h@level>Level @level</h@level>
}(level, list){
<div>End of level @level</div>
}
}
```

listContainer.scala.html

```
@(header: Html)(level:Int, items:Seq[Item])(footer: Html)
@import Item

<div style="margin-left: @{5*level}%">
@header
<ul id="list@level">

@items.map { item =>
<li>@listItem(item)</li>
}
</ul>
@footer
</div>
```

Item.java Model

```
package models;

import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class Item{
public String User;
public LocalTime timestamp;
public String message;

public Item(String User, LocalTime timestamp, String message){
    this.User = User;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

listItem.scala.html

```
@(item:Item)

<style>

li.item span{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<li class="item"> <span>@item.User</span> <span>[@item.timestamp]</span> > @item.message </li>
```

When I run the app I get this error:

```
/Users/andrei/play-java/app/views/listContainer.scala.html:7: '.' expected but ';' found.
<ul id="list@level">
```

and I can not understand why.

Comment: where is your line 7, could you mark it?

Comment: <li>@listItem(item)</li>  (listContainer.scala.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is following, when you're importing the class `Item`, you did it wrong.

```
@import Item
```

But it should be

```
@import models.Item
```

Comment: even if it is not in the models directory?

Comment: of course, this is how import is working, just try it out by yourself